# Local variable in template for async pipe (angular 2+)

Tags: angular

my template have something like...

```
<div> {{ (profile$ | async).username}}</div>
<div> {{ (profile$ | async).email}}</div>
```

Is there a way to assign (profile | async) to a local variable?  having to type it out for every single field is bad for readability.

Thanks.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The best approach would be to create a new component, e.g. in this case `app-profile` and to pass `profile | async` to that component. Inside the component you can name the variable whatever you like.

```
<app-profile [profile]="profile | async"></app-profile>
```

Another way of doing it would be to use *ngIf with the 'as' syntax

```
<ng-container *ngIf="profile | async as p">
   <div> {{ p.username }}</div>
   <div> {{ p.email }}</div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Yes, I have seen a few a few example doing this, which is probably better for re-usability.  Thanks!

Comment: If you're using ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush, this doesn't really help, since you'd end up using an observable in the app-profile component to respond to changes in the profile @Input

Comment: @chrismarx no, in this example the _app-profile_ input variable _profile_ would not be an observable.  Each value that passes through outer, observable _profile_ would be piped through async, which is going to push a single value into the input.  That will trigget the OnPush change detection, which will cause _app-profile_ to render the new value.

Comment: @JasonJackson hmm, I think you're right, I forgot that onpush updates both on changes to something async as well as "@Inputs"

Answer (score 75):

Since Angular 4.0.0-rc.1 (2017-02-24), you can use the enhanced `*ngIf` syntax. This let's you assign the result of an `*ngIf` condition in a template local variable:

```
<div *ngIf="profile$ | async as profile">
    <div>{{profile.username}}</div>
    <div>{{profile.email}}</div>
</div>
```

The updated [`*ngIf` documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgIf-directive.html) goes into further detail and gives many good examples using `async` and `*ngIf` together.

Be sure to also check out the `then` and `else` statements of `*ngIf`.

Cory Rolan has made a [short tutorial](https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-async-data-binding-with-ng-if-and-ng-else) that you can digest in 5–10 minutes.

Comment: @Hinrich no, it doesn't matter actually. async pipes are memoized and internally the same subscribtion gets used. the only benefit is the readability

Comment: @Phil In fact, it is not like this, it is better to use a variable because if you use the pipe several times it will create a different subscriptions for each one, which maybe it is not what you want. You could check it easily logging subscription.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit hacky but I've seem a lot of examples using something like this:

```
<template ngFor let-profile [ngForOf]="profile$ | async">
  <div> {{ profile.username }}</div>
  <div> {{ profile.avatar }}</div>
  <div> {{ profile.email }}</div>
  ...
</template>
```

Comment: How is this different from `<div *ngFor="let profile of profile$ | async">`?

Comment: @torazaburo With the one you mentioned you're creating a `<div>` wrapper on every iteration. The [`<template>` element](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html#!#template) doesn't generate any output and is just used to define a block in your layout, however `<template>` doesn't support the short syntax (*ngFor) only the long one.

Comment: Can I use `template` to simply assign a variable to the latest value of an observable, without it being an array that I want to loop over?

Comment: @torazaburo Maybe, but I don't see any reason to do that in your template instead of on its own controller. You can still use an observable in your template and add another observer to it from your controller to run whatever piece of code when its value changes. You'll have more power by making this variable assignment you mentioned from within your controller. Hope that made any sense to you.

Answer (score 4):

There is an alternative but it is more tedious. The solution that Günter Zöchbauer propsed mitigates that fact.

The alternative would be to subscribe to the observable inside of the component and then use the subscription variable in your template. You must unsubscribe the subscription in the OnDestroy event to prevent memory leaks. The async pipe do that for you. That is why the accepted solution is cleaner. But if you dont want to create a new component this is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

If you want access to object on inner `vm$` like this type `vm$: Observable<{ profile: {} }>`;

try below snippet and don't forget `?` mark.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(vm$ | async)?.profile as profile">
  <div> {{ profile.username }}</div>
  <div> {{ profile.email }}</div>
</ng-container>
```